# Compute volume of the tetrahedron from circumsphere test

Tags: geometry, 3d, computational-geometry

I'm working on a computational geometry algorithm.

In every iteration I solve the matrix below, where **(a,b,c,d) are the vertices of a tetrahedron**, and **e is an arbitrary point**. Solving the determinant of the matrix one can test whether point **e** lies inside the circumphere of the tetrahedron.

The determinant is positive if **e** lies inside the circumphere of tetrahedron **(a,b,c,d)**, negative if outside, and zero if they are cospherical or coplanar.

[image]

*However I would also need the volume of the tetrahedron.*

**Can I compute the volume of the tetrahedron from the above matrix with minimal overhead?** Or should I compute it independently?